# ¿Cómo cargar una dll en mi proyecto?

Tags: c#, aplicación-web

Tengo el siguiente código

```
lRutaBinarios = "C:\Program Files\Compacw\AdminPAQ"
SDKAdmin.SetCurrentDirectory(lRutaBinarios);    

// Inicializa el SDK de Admin
lError = SDKAdmin.fSetNombrePAQ(lNombrePAQ);
if (lError != 0)
{
Console.Write(SDKAdmin.rError(lError));
return;
}

// Abrir empresa y SDK
lError = SDKAdmin.fAbreEmpresa(CompanyName);

if (lError != 0)
{
Console.Write("Error SDK" + lError);
}
```

E importo la dll de la siguiente manera

```
[DllImport("MGW_SDK.dll")]
public static extern int fSetNombrePAQ(string aNombrePAQ);
```

El error esta en que no puedo cargar la dll y me arroja el siguiente mensaje de error

> No se puede cargar el archivo DLL 'MGW_SDK.dll': No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Estuve trabajando con una aplicación de escritorio y realizaba los mismos métodos para la conexión y carga de la ddl y funciona perfectamente, pero con este nuevo proyecto web no me funciona. ¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de por qué me arroja el mensaje de error?

Comment: ¿Tienes la .dll como referencia dentro de tu proyecto?

Comment: No no la tengo, ya que cuando intento agregarla me marca el siguiente error `No se puede agregar una referencia a 'C:\Program Files\Compacw\AdminPAQ\MGW_SDK.dll'. Asegure de que tiene acceso al archivo y de que es un ensamblado o componente COM válido`

Comment: Miguel buenas tardes pudiste solucionar el problema de la carga de la DLL?

Comment: Hola buenas tardes Ruben, lamentablemente no. Aun no eh podido solucionar mi problema

Comment: Pudsite solucionar el error? He tratado por varias horas la solución pero igual al darle permisos a las carpetas sigo teniendo el mismo error.

Comment: Lograste resolverlo? yo tambien tengo el mismo problema.

Comment: en la pagina de Compaqi tienen dos ejemplos compilados, te tienes que registrar e irte al foro y podir que te manden algun ejemplo ya compilado en c# Y VB.NET, yo descargue uno y lo modifique para mi proyecto y solo asi fue que funciono y ahora tiene mas de 7 meses que le mando datos de mi sistema a la base de datos de adminpaq usando el SDK

Comment: Que tal Manny, ya tienen esos ejemplos para el proyecto web?, la última vez que investigue sobre el tema no encontré nada en los foros de contpaqi

Answer (score 1):

El error puede deberse a que no en todas las computadoras la carpeta de Program Files se llame asi, un ejemplo mas sencillo es que por ejemplo en el mio se llama archivo de programas.

Otro error común puede ser los permisis de windows para acceder hasta estas rutas, Yo te recomendaria guardar tu archivo dll en el programData(Que no requiere permisos, es mas sencillo acceder y todos los equipos se llama igual)

En C# .net se puede acceder a esta carpeta mediante

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)
```

La cual te da acceso a el programData del equipo actual, sin importar la ruta o el usuario. Para tener mas control crea una carpeta (Mediante codigo) en el programData, asi puedes tener varios archivos en un misma parte

Saludos!!!

Comment: Voy a probar  te aviso como me fue, Gracias...

Comment: Que tal Alejo Florez, pues ni poniéndolo en esa carpeta, me siguió marcando el mismo error. Gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Mira migue, el errors entonces esta directamente en la forma en la que estas buscando el archivo, me explico, este error normalmente se ocasiona cuando tu archivo no ha sido encontrado (o tu archivo no esta bien desarrollado), esto ocasiona una interrupción en losmodulos, según veo tu solo estas importando el archivo **MGW_SDK.dll**
Mas no estas agregando la ruta exacta, intenta ver si tu ruta es la correcta

Comment: La ruta si es la correcta, ya que comente lo utilizo de la misma manera en una aplicación de escritorio y sin ningún fallo ni problema y de igual manera solo importo el archivo MGW_SDK

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que cambiar el directorio actual de tu aplicación (no la aplicación) a la carpeta  donde están los dll de contpaq.

Primero tienes que buscar en el registro de Windows la ubicación de la carpeta de contpaq.

Luego cambias a esa carpeta, si no recuerdo mal se hace con:

```
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(path)
```

Si no puedes lo comentas, para buscar mis antiguos programas donde hacía uso del sdk de contpaq.

Comment: Que tal buen día Luis, ya hice lo de buscar en el registro de Windows la carpeta y me muestra la carpeta en donde se encuentra la dll, pero sigue sin cargarme dicha dll

Comment: ¿hiciste lo de Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(path)? path es la ruta de la carpeta que sacas del registro.

Debes usar Directory.SetCurrentDirectory antes de cualquier llamada al SDK de contpaq.

Otra cosa que también debes hacer antes de llamar a SetCurrentDirectory, debes verificar que efectivamente en esa carpeta estén los Dlls o si no están en otra carpeta dentro de esa carpeta.

Comment: De hecho el `SetCurrentDirectory(path)` no me marca ningún error, el error se genera en`fSetNombrePAQ()`  . Los dll si se encuentran en la carpeta, de hecho pensé lo mismo que no estaban y cree una nueva ruta donde guarde el dll pero sigue marcándome el mismo error

Comment: Ya encontré parte del código que utilizaba en mis antiguos proyectos, veo que no utilizaba SetCurrentDirectory sino una función de Windows que importaba desde una dll, te dejo el código, pero usaba vb.net:     <DllImport("KERNEL32", EntryPoint:="SetCurrentDirectoryA")> _
    Public Function SetCurrentDirectory(ByVal pPtrDirActual As String) As Integer
    End Function

Comment: Que tal mira ya lo pase a `c#`, y quedo de la siguiente manera `[DllImport("KERNEL32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetCurrentDirectoryA")]
 public static extern int SetCurrentDirectory(string pPtrDirActual);` y sigue igual.
Bueno solo me funciono una vez pero ya después volvió a seguirme diciendo que no se podía cargar la dll

Comment: Llamas a la función cada vez que quieres utilizar alguna de las funciones del sdk de contpaq?

Comment: Si cada que quiero utilizar el SDK, mando llamar alguna funcion, por ejemplo `// Inicializa el SDK de Admin
lError = SDKAdmin.fSetNombrePAQ(lNombrePAQ);` donde lo incializo y este en donde quiero abrir la empresa `// Abrir empresa y SDK
lError = SDKAdmin.fAbreEmpresa(CompanyName);`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68729/discussion-between-luis-and-miguel).

Comment: Añadí un par de comentarios en el chat, pero creo que tengo una idea de porqué no te carga la dll. Al ser proyecto de asp.net, tengo entendido que por default tiene permisos restringidos, y supongo que al estar intentando usar código "no administrado", y es parte de uno de los permisos, es cuando bota el error. También el acceso a carpetas del disco duro está definido en permisos, recuerda que la aplicación web se ejecuta con un tipo de usuario específico, y generalmente no tiene todos los permisos de acceso.

Comment: Entonces como podría brindarle a cualquier usuario permisos para ingresar a dichas carpetas desde asp.net?

Comment: Hasta donde se, no es al usuario que usa tu web al que le das permiso, es a la aplicación que ejecuta asp.net, a cada aplicación se le asigna un "pool", y cada pool se ejecuta bajo un usuario de windows. Aquí lo explican muy bien: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16678016/8512394

Comment: Ok muchas gracias, voy a probar